# What is the CSS property that makes a <fieldset> fully enclose it's contents?

Tags: html, css

I am using `<fieldsets>` to group but it always gives me a message in the IDE saying that the `<legend>` is missing. I decided to try and simulate the `<fieldset>` with a `<div>.`

```
.grid-select .group {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 1.667em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 89;
  padding-top: 1.667em;
}
```

This does not work for me as it seems like the `<div>` does not wrap around other `<div>` elements inside my fieldset in the same was as when I used `<fieldset>` .

Is there some other property that a `<fieldset>` has that I don't have?

Note that inside the .group the `<div>` have display: inline; and float: left

Comment: Why don't you use empty `<legend></legend>` tag?

Comment: Doesn't that produce an empty legend? I just want an enclosing box which the fieldset provides but using a DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that inside the .group the  have display: inline; and float: left

This is exactly the problem. Floated elements do not contribute to the height of their parent. In other words, the surrounding `div` thinks the floated elements non-existent. A good workaround for this is to set the `.group` to `overflow: hidden`, which does cause it to consider all children for its size calculation.

But `legend` elements are optional. If only your IDE is complaining about it, fix the IDE. You shouldn't substitute a `fieldset` for a mere `div` only for that reason.

Comment: Thanks but interesting as when I used fieldset instead of the DIV with exactly the same CSS then it does "enclose". Do you have any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Fieldsets simply behave differently from divs. It may be beyond mere CSS properties, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks - The IDE is VS21012. Message is stating it's an HTML validation failure. I guess valid HTML requires it to have a legend.

Comment: Not sure about HTML 4, but in HTML 5 it's certainly optional.

Comment: Someone needs to tell Microsoft :-) It's says "HTML5 validation failure"